# RabbitMQ, trouble getting hello world example to work on anything but localhost

Tags: linux, rabbitmq, message-queuing, messaging

I'm learning RabbitMQ and have run the hello world example at http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html without problems on localhost.  Now I want to test messaging from my PC to a different server, receive.py never seems to get any messages.  Perhaps I'm not specifying the hostnames correctly?

Receive.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import json

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='66.175.x.x'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

print ' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C'

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    data = json.loads(body)
    print "Log filename is " + data["filename"]
    print data["content"]

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='hello',
                      no_ack=True)

channel.start_consuming()
```

send.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import json
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
logdata = open(filename, 'r').read()

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='66.175.x.x'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='logupload')
n = filename.rfind('\\')
if n != -1:
    filename = filename[n + 1:]
data = {"filename":filename, "logdata":logdata}

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='logupload',
                      body=json.dumps(data))
connection.close()
print "sent %s %d bytes" % (filename, len(logdata))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RabbitMQ -- http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html

See the frame_max. Seems like 128KB is supported by default. You may want to check that setting in your installation.

Comment: Note I'm using RabbitMQ.  File is sent up as a JSON encoded string (for now).

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: I created a config file specifyinga large frame_max, didn't seem to affect the behavior however.  My config. file is : 
    {rabbit, [{frame_max, 20000000}, {log_levels, [{connection, info}]}]}
].

Comment: It looks like Pika is limited to 128K data size.  Message me if you know how to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure rabbitmq is actually listening on port 5672 and that the port is open in your Linode server's firewall.

In your config, RABBITMQ_NODE_IP_ADDRESS should be blank, RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT should be 5672.

Comment: I checked I don't have a firewall running and have no rabbitmq config. file.  This morning it started working with no changes.  My next problem is that smaller log files (~10K) are not being received but larger files (>= ~100K) are sent OK.  Is there some type of buffering that prevents smaller data payloads from being sent or received?

Comment: Actually current behavior is that small files (~64 bytes) are being received, but larger files (~52K) are not.  What would prevent one file from being transferred over another?